# Quicker way than "try" and "except" ? - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm often having code written as follows

```
try:
  self.title = item.title().content.string
except AttributeError, e:
  self.title = None
```

---

Is there a quicker way of dealing with this? a one-liner?

Comment: You've asked for both "quicker" and "less code".  Do you have a preference?  Or do you magically want both.  Anything with less code may turn out to be slower.  Exceptions are really fast.

Comment: I think he meant "quicker to type" rather than "quicker to run".

Comment: @S.Lott yup "quicker to type", sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What exceptions are you getting from `item.title()`?  The bare `except` (horrible practice!) doesn't tell us.  If it's an AttributeError (where `item` doesn't have a `title` method, for example),

```
self.title = getattr(item, 'title', lambda: None)()
```

might be the one-liner you seek (but performance won't be *enormously* different, mind you;-).

**Edit**: as the OP entirely changed the question (it was originally just using `self.title()`, it's now using `self.title().content.string`, and does specifically catch `AttributeError` rather than using a bare `except`), the previous version of this answer of course doesn't apply any more. The proper answer now is: attempting a one-liner is an absurd approach, when the chain of attribute references &c keeps growing longer and longer (how many will there be next time, nine?  Since they jumped from one to three with the first edit...;-).

And with no idea of which of the many elementary operations expressed by that long, [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)-scoffing chain of references might raise the AttributeError, any attempt at optimization would be flying rather blind, too.

Comment: @Alex thanks!! I changed the code in the question, not sure how I can adapt the one liner. item is a BeautifulSoup node.

Comment: @RadiantHex, that one-liner doesn't help w/a long chain of attribute references.  What's the problem your try/except wards against -- no `title` method, no `content` attribute in its results, no `string` attribute in `content`...?  If you're simultaneously warding against multiple such problems, no one-liner makes sense; if just one, then a `getattr` at that spot, with the right default value, might (microscopically) help, but don't expect solid performance gains!

Comment: thank you so much! and thanks for adding interesting content to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

In one line, although I’d only recommend this in 5% of all use cases.

```
self.title = item.title().content.string if hasattr(item, 'title') else None
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the AttributeError happens on `string`:

```
self.title = getattr(item.title().content, 'string', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should know ahead of time whether or not an object has a given attribute. It is a bad sign when you have an object but do not know what it is.
- You retrieve three attributes in your try block. A try block should contain as little code as possible. You could let an error pass silently if a different attribute is missing than you think.
- `getattr` lets you have a default value, but typically should not be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your question focuses on the speed of this operation. First, why do you think this operation is slow? Second, there isn't a faster way to access the attributes.  Even trying to avoid the catch by checking for the attribute first will likely be slower, simply because of the Python conditionals needed to check if the attribute exists.  Also, hasattr attempts to read the attribute, and catches AttributeError, returning False.  So checking for the attribute will actually involve a try/except anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about a two-liner?

```
try: self.title = item.title().content.string
except AttributeError, e: self.title = None
```

Denser, less readable, but you really save two keypresses!