# Python, dictionary copy and update doesn't work?

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

Why does the following code show `None` for b, and not {'a': 1, 'e': 2}?
Python 2.7.3

```
>>>> d = {'a' :1 }
>>>> b = d.copy().update({'e':2})
>>>> print b
None
>>>> d.update({'c':3})
>>>> print d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: You don't have to type 'print' to print those values to the console, by the way. Just type the name and press enter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[dict.update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) modifies the dict but returns `None`. This is why

```
b = d.copy().update({'e':2})
```

sets `b` to equal `None`, while

```
d.update({'c':3})
```

modifies `d`.

A lot of Python methods behave this way. For example, `list.sort` and `random.shuffle` also modify an object and return `None`. I think Python does this to discourage [long "Law-of-Demeter-scoffing" chains of references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443559/190597) because they do not improve readability and make finding where exceptions are raised harder.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that dict.update() returns none.
I was about to answer my own question, but you beat me to it!
Here's the the documentation, http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html