# Change all column names in chained operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2]], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

I'm aware I can do the following to change all column names in a dataframe:

```
df.columns = ['d', 'e']
```

How can I change all column names in a chained operation? For example, I would like to do something like:

```
df=(
    df.rename all column names
    .reset_index()
)
```

The only way I can find is to use `df.rename` and build a dictionary with the old and new column pairs but that looks very ugly. Are there any more elegant solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16667215/5916727

Comment: Not quite. I want to give columns completely new names. There's no need to reference old names.

Comment: How do you intend to map old_col_names -> new_col_names without any of: ordinal position, dictionary map, or lambda function?

Comment: That's my question. I just want to give all columns complete new names. There's no relation or mapping to the old names.

Comment: Ah so the only issue is chaining it?

Comment: That's right df.columns = ... does what I need but I need to do this in chained operations. df.columns = ... does not return the df so can't be used in chained operations.

Comment: Note that long chained operations is [consider by some experts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443559/190597) a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Nevertheless, you could use `df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, ['d','e']))`.

Comment: Thanks unutbu but I'm only chaining 2 operations here 

Comment: I personally despise the yearning for one-liners; for readability, i would write a function `def renamer(df, cols); df.columns=cols; return df`. then call `renamer(df)` in the chaining.

Comment: @unutbu I'm aware of this option and I think it's not very elegant. If I can do df.rename(columns=['d','e']), that'll be perfect.

Comment: Then you could do as @jp_data_analysis suggests, or just bite the bullet and write the somewhat long-winded `df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, ['d','e']))`. You could raise a [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+rename+columns) for `df.rename(columns=['d','e'])`, but at the moment that is not part of the Pandas API.

Comment: There is already a github issue proposing `df.rename(columns=['d','e'])` : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14829

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I find chained operation makes code more organised. See one of Pandas developer's blog https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining

Comment: @unutbu it's great it's already been raised and worked on. Thanks for the info. Looks like at the moment there's no simpler way of doing it.

Comment: @Allen: You could use @jp_data_analysis's idea (`def renamer...`) and then do `df.pipe(renamer)` -- similar to what tomaugspurger does in the blog.

Comment: @unutbu, it seems there's an answer in the comments of the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @unutbu for pointing to a [git hub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14829), it turns out this can be done via set_axis from one of the comments there:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2]], columns=['a', 'b'])   
df
Out[21]: 
   a  b
0  1  2

df2 = (
    df.set_axis(['d','e'], axis=1, inplace=False)
    .reset_index()
)
df2
Out[18]: 
   index  d  e
0      0  1  2
```